# how to verify whether paytm client id and secret key are valid ones?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, paypal

I have a react website with a payment module for PayPal.

It has an ability for cloud provision as well, for which, when the user requests for provision, he enters the form data and at that time, I will be taking his PayPal Client ID and secret ID as well, using which I will be making him a new provision

Is there a way to verify that the PayPal client ID and secret values are valid ones?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An API request to get an access token, https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/get-an-access-token-curl/